# MultiNode Tree Picker validation

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7, propertyeditor

I want to capture the submit event of multinode tree picker in order to add a validation message that will be shown when the user is selecting more than the max no. of nodes allowed.

We can capture the save n publish event using "ContentService", so I was wondering if we can capture the submit event of property editors as well?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You can create a new plugin... and copy some code from the original umbraco controllers, and update that submit part. I looked into the treepicker the submit is not firing an event other then the callback given by the multinodepicker.

Comment: Yes, I will do the same now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is only possible if you extend a property editor or rewrite it and add validation to it.

You can always create a custom property editor and add customizations to that.

Hope this helps!

Thanks